# Java EL parser experiments

Tags: java, el

I'm playing full of curiosity with the EL parser of java, the goal is to make a .jsp execute java code in oneline

This is the code:

```
            ..... 
            String input1 = request.getParameter("ce");
            ELProcessor elp = new ELProcessor();
            Object sys = elp.eval(input1);
            Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
            String fromobj = String.valueOf(sys);
            out.println(fromobj);
            .....
```

It works fine if I provide in input something simple, like:
System.getProperty('user.name')

If I provide in input something more complex like:
System.currentTimeMillis(); System.getProperty('user.name'), just the last one ( System.getProperty('user.name')) gets executed.. why?

And how can I fix that behavior?

Comment: How do you know the other one isn't executed?

Comment: @khelwood I expect the output of both parts to get printed. I actually get the output of just the last one

Answer (score 2):

What are you expecting to happen?  There can only be 1 return value from the evaluation, and the last statement does exactly that.

Remember EL is an **expression** language.  Not a **statement** language.  There are real differences between those.  Statements are like complete sentences.  They are composed of 1 or more expressions followed by some place to store the result (ie like an assignment)  Expressions result in a value, but aren't complete.  They don't have assignments in them.  The first expression `System.currentTimeMillis()` probably executed, but since there was nothing to store it in (ie no assignment) you can't really be sure it ran.

EL is meant to be used for single line expressions that return a value.  I'm not even sure more than one expression is valid or would even really work if it can't store the return value somewhere.  If you stored both results into a List and returned that List then it might show both values, BUT again EL IS NOT JAVA.  It's not a general purpose programming language.

Comment: thanks for your answer! then what alternative could I use to run java code from a .jsp?

Comment: If you want to compile actual java code you'll need to use the JavaCompiler to do that.  https://www.developer.com/design/an-introduction-to-the-java-compiler-api/